# How do I reset the /odom topic back to 0 without restarting the robot?

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot, quaternion, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using this callback function because I want to tell the robot to move a specified angle. I was wondering if there is a way to restart the /odom topic back to 0 for simplicity purposes. Your help is really appreciated!

I am using ROS Indigo and I have a create turtlebot base

```
def odometry_cb(self, data):
        pose = data.pose.pose
        quaternion = (pose.orientation.x, pose.orientation.y, pose.orientation.z, pose.orientation.w)
        euler = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(quaternion)
        roll = euler[0]
        pitch = euler[1]
        yaw = euler[2] 
        yaw_angle = (yaw*(180/math.pi))
        self._last_yaw_angle = yaw_angle
        print(self._last_yaw_angle)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213049/how-do-i-reset-the-/odom-topic-back-to-0-without-restarting-the-robot?/) by [shahvineet98](https://answers.ros.org/users/23078/shahvineet98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-07-10**:
It would be useful if you name the robot you use and which package.

**Comment by [shahvineet98](https://answers.ros.org/users/23078/shahvineet98/) on 2015-07-10**:
I am sorry for not clarifying earlier but I updated that in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is how odometry is reset for Kobuki:

```
void KobukiRos::subscribeResetOdometry(const std_msgs::EmptyConstPtr /* msg */)
{
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Kobuki : Resetting the odometry. [" << name << "].");
  joint_states.position[0] = 0.0; // wheel_left
  joint_states.velocity[0] = 0.0;
  joint_states.position[1] = 0.0; // wheel_right
  joint_states.velocity[1] = 0.0;
  odometry.resetOdometry();
  kobuki.resetOdometry();
  return;
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [vinjk](https://answers.ros.org/users/21648/vinjk/) with karma: 96 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you do have a Kobuki base, you can use the `~commands/reset_odometry` topic of type `std_msgs/Empty` for this, as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_node)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shahvineet98](https://answers.ros.org/users/23078/shahvineet98/) on 2015-07-10**:
This is exactly what I am looking for but is it possible on a create base?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-07-10**:
I think if you search in the source code where this topic is defined and how its callback function looks like, you can copy it for the create.

**Comment by [OsgoodWu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32862/osgoodwu/) on 2017-12-05**:
Hello, I just creat a publisher topic to publish the ~commands/reset_odometry , but I find the turtlebot doesn't change it's pose ,do you know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far I can see there is no such service for the create node.

I guess you would have to add a service for that yourself in

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/blob/832a645fc459823b76b8f340dc8d9695a40d718f/create_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py

Maybe the `_robot_reboot(self):` function does what you want but you will have to add a service to call it externally.

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1